# C : While taking user input in while loop, it goes as infinite loop - user input

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, user-input

I am trying to take user input in my program but once user inputs 'y' to continue the loop one more time, while loop goes crazy and ends up in an infinite loop or at times, exits the loop without taking scanf input.

```
char in = 'y';
while(in == 'y'){

  // Code

  printf("do you wanna continue?");
  scanf("%c",&in); //enter y to continue
}
```

Comment: What is `%ch` ?

Comment: What happens if you enter "yh" ?

Comment: `scanf("%ch",&in);`? Make it `scanf("%c",&in);`.

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page and take note of the return value. It might be eof

Comment: %ch is a typo that I made while writing the question here. It still isn't behaving normally.

Answer (score 2):

To scan into char variable you have to use `%c`
like this

> scanf("%c", &in);

Comment: I am sorry about the %ch but that was a typo.

Even without the 'h', it asks for once and then doesn't run scanf command again. Just prints the statement the second time and exits the loop.